# How can I hide a form within a web application until a button is clicked for login and register purposes

Tags: html, jsp

I have a login jsp page where users can login in to my web application, I have also a sign Up form where user can register if they are not members. I'm trying to do the login and sign up forms in one JSP called login.jsp. Login part works fine However, I am unable to display the sign up form when a user clicks on the signup button.

Here is the login.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <meta name="description" content="Login and Registration Form with HTML5 and CSS3" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="html5, css3, form, switch, animation, :target, pseudo-class" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate-custom.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit(){
         if(validateForm()) {
        document.loginForm.submit();
         }
    }
    function checkSubmit(e)
    {
       if(e && e.keyCode == 13)
       {
          document.forms[0].submit();
       }
    }


    function validateForm()
    {


    var c=document.forms["loginForm"]["name"].value;
    if (c==null || c=="")
      {
      alert("Username must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
    var d=document.forms["loginForm"]["password"].value;
    if (d==null || d=="")
      {
      alert("Password must be filled out");
      return false;
      }

    return true;
    }


</script>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container">
            <!-- Codrops top bar -->
            <div class="codrops-top">
                <a href="">
                    <strong>&laquo; Previous Demo: </strong>Responsive Content Navigator
                </a>
                <span class="right">
                    <a href=" http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/27/login-and-registration-form-with-html5-and-css3/">
                        <strong>Back to the Codrops Article</strong>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div><!--/ Codrops top bar -->
            <header>
                <h1> Login to view Cricket Fixtures and scores</h1>
                <nav class="codrops-demos">
                    <a href="index.html">Demo 1</a>
                    <a href="index2.html">Demo 2</a>
                    <a href="/CricketWebApplication/jsp/login.jsp" class="current-demo">Demo 3</a> <!-- index.html3 b4 need to change to login.jsp -->
                </nav>
            </header>
            <section>               
                <div id="container_demo" >
                    <!-- hidden anchor to stop jump http://www.css3create.com/Astuce-Empecher-le-scroll-avec-l-utilisation-de-target#wrap4  -->
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="login" class="animate form">
                            <form method="get" id = "loginForm" name="loginForm" action="/CricketWebApplication/LoginServlet" autocomplete="on"> 
                                <h1>Log in</h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your  username </label>
                                    <input id="username" name="name" onKeyPress="javascript:return checkSubmit(event)"/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                                    <input id="password" name="password" onKeyPress="javascript:return checkSubmit(event)"/> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="keeplogin"> 
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
                                    <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
                                </p>
                                <p class="login button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">
                                    Not a member yet ?
                                    <a href= "" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>

           <div id="register" class="animate form">
                            <form  action="/CricketWebApplication/LoginServlet" autocomplete="on"> 
                                <h1> Sign up </h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
                                    <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
                                    <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/> 
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                                </p>
                                <p class="signin button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">  
                                    Already a member ?
                                    <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>  
            </section>
        </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to switch the css of the div from  `display: none;` to `display: block;`

```
<script>function unhideDiv()
{
  document.getElementById('divid').style = "display: block;";
}
</script>
<div style='display: none;' id='divid'>...</div>
<input type='button' onClick='unhideDiv()' />
```

Or lookup fancier jquery methods. They've got div-popups and everything now.